# Why this Future's method is blocking main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Future<Integer> calculate(Integer input) {
    return executor.submit(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return input * input;
    });
}

public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
    Main m = new Main();
    System.out.println(m.calculate(5).get());
    System.out.println("Main");
```

We submit Callable to Executor with 2 threads, but when i tell `m.calculate(5).get()` it block main thread.
So, I can't understand, when and why should I use `Future` if it blocks the main thread and doesn't run asynchronously?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--

Comment: The issue is not with the `Future` itself here. the `get` method waits for it to complete and returns the future's return value, so by calling `get` you are explicitly blocking the main thread.

Comment: @BackSlash, It means that `Future` was not created for asynchronous task withot blocking ?

Comment: @Rarity7- It means that it *is* asynchronous but the way you are using it makes it synchronous-like.

Comment: In general terms for example I am digging a well; it's upto you to sit & watch/wait for hours me doing that or do something else meanwhile & come up later whenever you get free.

Comment: @NayanWadekar This is the problem that i can't do anything, when i call `get()`. For example if i want make Http request and return JSON String. When i call `get() it will wait long time until request is done.  Here is the problem that i can't understand, why it is called parallel if all work occurs at the time of the call.

Comment: You seem to be missing the fact that it's the call to `get()` that's blocking. You can do _anything you want_ before you call `get()` and the task represented by the `Future` will run concurrently with whatever else you're doing.

Comment: @Rarity7- it is only non-parallel if you call `get`. What else do you expect `get` to do if the result is not ready? You can check if the result is ready with `isDone()`

Comment: Ohh, i got it. Thank you guys.))

Comment: I really missed, that i can call `get()` separately from `calculate` method, to give `Future` time to complete!!))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look into the documentation of `Future::get` it says: "*Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.*" By calling this method you agree to wait for the result in the main thread.

You can check if Future has completed by calling `Future::isDone`, which returns boolean.

**In your scenario it can be used like this**

```
public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
    Main m = new Main();
    Future<Integer> futureInt = m.calculate(5);
    // do some other asynchronous task or something in main thread while futureInt is doing its calculations
    // and then call Future::get
    int result = futureInt.get();
```

See: [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())

Comment: It means that `Future` was not created for asynchronous task withot blocking ?

Comment: It means that Future is just a placeholder for the result of your task, which may or may not be present at the time you call Future::get.

Answer (score 5):

`Future` is indeed a very limited abstraction, in more realistic cases you should use `CompletableFuture` instead. `Future` is a pretty old class (since java 1.5 I guess) so the understanding of the industry has gradually evolved in the field of concurrent programming,

Nevertheless, it can still be useful by itself.

What if instead of spawning one future and immediately calling `get` on it, we would like to spawn many tasks and store the result in some list:

```
List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>(10);
for(int i = 0 ; i< 10; i++) {
   futures.add(calculate(<some_integer>));
}
// at this point all futures are running concurrently
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
   futures.get(i).get(); // will either return immediately or we'll block the main thread but the point is that all the calculations will run concurrently
}
```

Comment: Though it should be mentioned, that for the many tasks you'd probably use streams today: `IntStream.range(0, 10).map(this::calculate).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @Amadán Streams serve a different purpose. Though it's true the code in this answer could be replaced with a _parallel_ stream. However, you can't launch a parallel stream, do other stuff, then retrieve the result of the stream later—not without offloading the terminal operation call to another thread.

Comment: @Slaw You are right about streams not easily allowing to parallelize the batch processing and some different task for some TaskRunner. Still I think defining a stream and then running the collect() operation as a parallel task in some executor is a good idea in most cases. I'd say creating and managing your own threads is rarely needed.